# Begin new chapter with an odd-numbered page

Tags: numbering, chapters, book-design

Is there an easy way (command? / method?) to start each new chapter of your book with an odd numbered page? This would make sure that if you print the book the beginning of each chapter is printed on a right page of the printout. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unclear question. Normally, a chapter always begins on the right page. Do you have a special class or `openany` option?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: `@Christian` : Thank you for welcoming me. I use `\chapter{chapter title}` but I get some beginning of chapters on even pages.

Comment: `@Mico` : I use `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}`

Comment: With book class every chapter should begin on an odd page unless you do something to confuse the page numbering or if you changed the default. You should show a complete minimal example.

Comment: a much clearer title would be "begin new chapter on an odd-numbered page", if that is what is really meant.

Comment: `@barbara` : Yes! I did that and then saw your comment! Thanks, retrospectively!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using a document class that recognizes the command `\chapter`, you could force every new `\part` and `\chapter` to start on an odd-numbered page (aka recto page) by specifying the option `openright` when executing `\documentclass`.

---

*Addendum*: Consider the following MWE (minimum working example) that employs the `book` document class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\end{document}
```

If you compile it, you'll find that Chapter 2 starts on page 3 -- an odd-numbered page. If you're *not* getting this behavior in your document, it must be because one or more instructions in your preamble are overriding the default behavior of the `book` document class.

Comment: I found out that the option `openright` is a default for the `book` document class, so I thought that my settings would be just fine even if I do not explicitly revoke the `openright` option, which btw someone [claims](http://texblog.org/2013/02/13/latex-documentclass-options-illustrated/#openright) that works only combined with the `twoside` option set also. Bottom line is that neither combination works for me (`openright` alone, with `twoside` or nothing) so I do not know if I should focus my debugging on a different cause (can something bypass these options for example?)

Comment: @pebox11 - An observation such as "neither combination works for me" is not actionable. Please consider editing your posting to show what your document preamble actually looks like: There must be something there that's overriding the default behavior of the `book` document class.

Answer (score 2):

Do this only if needed (I don't advise it really)

The labelling works and it works with `hyperref`, if that package is loaded after the patch.

`openright` is definitely easier (but won't provide odd numbers of course)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter} = 0
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \else
  \addtocounter{chapter}{1}%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \fi
}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think the OP meant to say that he/she wants chapters to start on odd-numbered pages rather than that the chapter numbers must only be odd. However, I may be wrong.

Comment: @Mico: I may be wrong, but literally: *each new chapter of your book with an odd number* --> odd chapter number? or odd page number

Comment: The OP's stated objective, "to start each new chapter of your book with an odd number", may have been worded somewhat infelicitously. Let's see if the OP sees fit to clarify his/her objective.

Comment: `@Mico` : You are correct, it is deduced from the context cause I refer to "...the beginning of each chapter" being "printed on a right page" which only happens when each new chapter corresponds to an odd page number. But `Christian` also is right in the sense that you shouldn't try hard to decode every original post! So thumbs up to both and restating the OP to fit clarifications.

Comment: @pebox11: I've thumbed up Mico's post already ;-)

Comment: `@Christian` : I can't, my `tex.stackexchange` magnitude ( :) ) does not allow me yet to thumb up comments!

Comment: @pebox11: You got my upvote already, can't give you more ;-)